# SQL syntax cast function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code where I first need to find the students with the lowest `ENROLL_PERIOD` and then after `join` a table with `grades`. The problem is that the data in my table `students` is stored as text. So before i can sort the data properly i need to use the `cast` function and make the `ENROLL_PERIOD` from the table `students` an integer. But where should i put it in the code? I keep getting syntax errors. Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want:

```
Select *
from (select top (100) s.*
      from students s 
      where PERSON_ID <> ''
      order by TRY_CAST(KonvENROLL_PERIOD AS INT)   
     ) s 
join grades g
  on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The column belongs in the `select`.  Also, use `try_cast()` to avoid errors:

```
Select *
from (select top (100) s.*, try_cast(ENROLL_PERIOD AS int) AS KonvENROLL_PERIOD
      from students s 
      where PERSON_ID <> '' 
      order by KonvENROLL_PERIOD ASC      
     ) s inner join
     grades g
     on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID;
```